# how to Detect when gesture is up, down, left and right Cocos2d-android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I know there are solutions in cocos2d-iphone. but i am stuck while implementing in cocos2d-android. Although google android provides [gesture support](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) natively.but i am not sure how can i use this in cocos2d-andoid.

I have a CCSprite that I want to move around using gestures. Problem is I'm completely new to Cocos2D. I want my sprite to perform some action when gesture is down, another action when gesture is right and same thing for left. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!